# Do all the sectors on a particular drive have to be physically contiguous with each other?

Tags: hard-drive

For example, if you have a drive C: and a drive D:, then do all the files on drive D: have to be physically contiguous with each other? And if you're creating a new drive E: and want to allocate 10 GB to drive E:, then will the allocating programs ONLY allocate 10 GB to drive E: if 10 GB on another drive are already physically contiguous?

Is it possible to be logically continuous and physically all-over-the-place in extreme cases?

I'm most interested in Windows, but Linux works as well.

Answer (score 2):

They must be *logically* contiguous as determined by the firmware on the drive. The firmware can remap physical sectors in order to accommodate for errors in the physical media, but it performs translation between logical and physical sectors.

**EDIT:**

> Is it possible to be logically continuous and physically all-over-the-place in extreme cases?

No need to look for an "extreme case" for this; flash media often rearranges physical locations on write in order to implement [wear leveling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wear_leveling).